# Why does form still submit when you have javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, forms

It appears that a form will still submit even when you have javascript completely disabled. I thought that it takes javascript for it to work... the onClick() or onSubmit() function fires which triggers the GET/POST request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. That means your browser manually sends the GET/POST request (without the event listeners firing). A lot of websites still have submit buttons for this very reason (i.e. a fallback).

You could remove the submit button, if you don't want users submitting the form.

Comment: Even then some browsers will submit when pressing enter... why having a form if you do not want to submit it?

Answer (score 4):

No , the submit action is triggered by `<input type="submit">` (Actually a button) Which is html processing command. Additionally you can submit the form by using button input type but rased a javascript function to submit a form. In the second case if the javascript is disabled , it isn't going to submit the form for you.

Lastly: onclick,onfocus,onblur etc. events and anything inside  are javascript. Mostly Other than that is not associate with javascript.

Hope you underatands

Answer (score 3):

Use JS to display the buttons in the first place. That way, they don't show up when the user disables JS and no one can submit your form and you do not have to remove the buttons from your code.